# How to get the text from an link on the master page?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a master page with a few links on it, not asp:Hyperlinks, just normal  tags.  The links are on a menu bar that runs along the top of the page.

Then on the child page, when I click a button, I want to be able to get the value of a specific link on the menu bar at the top of the screen on the code behind page.

Does anyone know if I can do this, and if so, how?

I'm using .net web forms.

Comment: From memory doesn't the standard `jQuery $("#someid")` of the element allow you access to the element since the document ready loads after the page has been rendered?

Comment: Yeah, but how does this give me the text of the link on the code behind?  If I submit a form on the child page, I want that text so I can use it when processing the form data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to access elements within the master page.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Some function for someID on your master page:
        $("#someID").toggle();
    });
</script>
```

Since the master page and child pages are rendered before the `(document).ready` method completes, it ensures that all elements built onto the final page are visible.

Placing the above script into your child page will allow you to access elements in the master page file.

You will just need to ensure you have a jQuery link/reference:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
</head>
```

EDIT #1:

For getting the text off the master page into the code-behind of the child page you can do this (add hidden field to child page):

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdField" Value="SomeValue" runat="server" />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Some function for someID on your master page:
        $("#hdField").value = ("#IDofLinkOnMasterPage").Value;
    });
</script>
```

Then when your form posts to the child code-behind, you can look for the value of the hidden field by doing this:

```
var x = hdField.Value.ToString();
```

Comment: But how does this give me it on the code behind?  If I submit a form on the child page, I want to grab the text of the link on the master page and use it in the form.

Comment: Do you want to get the text of the link on the master page and submit it to the code behind of the child page?

Comment: Added that for you in Edit#1

Comment: Thanks, this is the ticket.