# Is it possible to target a html element within a .aspx file from within the corresponding .cs file using ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am using Visual Studio 2019 to create web forms using ASP.NET. I have a `<p>` element in an .aspx file which I would like to change the text of from its corresponding .cs file when a condition is met.

ASPX:

```html
<div class="header-items">
    <p id="header-title">TITLE HERE</p>
</div>
```

CS:

```cs
if (// condition is met)
{
    // target header-title ID and change the innerHtml
}
```

I have thus far been unable to find a solution. This is a new language to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

We need to make use of `runat="server"` to make it visible to the .aspx.cs code-behind file.

For `innerHTML`:

ASPX:

```
<div class="header-items">
    <p id="header-title" runat="server">TITLE HERE</p>
</div>
```

CS:

```
header-title.innerHTML = "Some Title";
```

For a `StringBuilder` to fill a `literal`:

ASPX:

```
<form id="form1">
    <asp:Literal ID="lit1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</form>
```

CS:

```
StringBuilder ss = new StringBuilder();
ss.Append("<div style='background-color:blue;color:white;'>hello</div>");
lit1.Text = ss.ToString();
```

Comment: The header-title element is not available to the .cs file when using the `innerHTML` method.

Comment: Look in the example of my answer, you need to add `runat="server"` :)

Comment: I have, no success.

Comment: Are you using a .cs file or .aspx.cs? It goes inside your page_load method in the aspx.cs

Comment: it is in a Master.cs file (I'm using a master page which I should have mentioned, apologies) and is in the page_load method.

Comment: A .aspx has a .aspx.cs counterpart. They have the same names e.g: bob.aspx and bob.aspx.cs. You cannot converse between a master page front end and a aspx.cs back end without an intermediary such as jquery and or a hidden field, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56147996/how-to-get-the-text-from-an-link-on-the-master-page/56150744#56150744)

Comment: Even if the .cs file is the Master pages corresponding .cs file?

Comment: If that's the case then yes you can, see [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/1990347.aspx?How+to+access+Master+Page+controls+from+its+code+behind+page+) this is exactly the same as my answer though but it does aim to lay out a better process. See [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/User-Control-and-Master-Page/Codebehindandmasterpage.htm) and [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/1351075.aspx?Accessing+a+label+on+a+MasterPage+from+codebehind)